# Memory occupied by my Application keeps increasing with time in strongloop loopback application

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Memory occupied by my Application keeps increasing with time in strongloop loopback offline sync application https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-offline-sync
Also it creates many sub folders and a file in these sub folder named as memory-leak.js is unable to delete. How can I delete this file and why the memory occupied by my app is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Devug the application using strong loop process monitor.  It will give you some insights